# too much recursion when uploading image

Tags: ajax, jquery

When i am trying to upload image via ajax in local, browser show the error **too much recursion**. so i couldn't test that in locally, but its works in production on heroku

```
$('#fileupload_pers').fileupload({ 
    url: '/create_img_prs',
    add: function (e, data) {
                    $('#upload_pers').html('<p class="upl label label- 
success">Uploading....please wait</p>');
                    data.submit();
                },
    success: function (r) {
            //$('#upload').remove();
            $('#upload_pers').empty();
            $('#upload_pers').html('<p class="upl label label-success">Successfully 
 Uploaded Image</p>') ;
            $('#id_poster_pers').attr('value',r["id"]);
            $('#upload_pers').fadeOut(6000);
            }
  });
```

Comment: Please post more code, maybe you attach the event many times or something like that.

Comment: Where's the recursion in the first place?

Comment: @amtest  I am having the same issue. The link provided in the answer is dead. Can you give the new link or a solution to this.

Answer (score 8):

The error 'too much recursion' can be caused by (accidently) including jquery.fileupload.js twice.

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/2814

Comment: @Pieter I am having the same issue. The link you provided is dead. Can you give the new link or the solution to this nightmare.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"404 | This is not the web page you are looking for"*.